# How to set an element attribute in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

attribute of the elements keeps changing on click of it.
How to set that attribute by java script or any other method in robotframework , without clicking on it.

```
<input type="file" id="fileUploadInput" data-documenttype="" data-coveragecode="" multiple="">
```

After clicking on the element the attribute changes to

```
<input type="file" id="fileUploadInput" data-documenttype="Accident report" data-coveragecode="TDEL" multiple="">
```

How to inject the attribute or set these attribute without clicking in robot framework

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully changed element attributes using JavaScript. If the element's id is unique, try this:

```
Execute JavaScript          document.getElementById('id').className = "new_class_name";
```

If the element's id is not unique, you can make it unique with:

```
${id}=                      Set Variable                    something_unique
Assign ID to Element        //some_element                  ${id}
```